# why can't I remove the gray lines that is surrounding my image?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I have an image overlap another background_image. I want the image to have the same background color as the background image. I don't know why there is a gray color surrounding my logo image which is the blue one.

I have tried to made the image transparent and it didn't work

```
def main_screen():
global root
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x800")
background_image = PhotoImage(file="assets/Aim high.png")
background_label = Label(root,image = background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth = 1 , relheight = 1)
root.title("Account Login")
top_text=Label(root,text="Welocme to FitQuest",bg="#000000",font=("Calibri", 45))
top_text.pack(pady=0, anchor =tkinter.CENTER)

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="Login", command=login)
button.place(relx=0.48, rely=0.3, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="Register", command=register)
button.place(relx=0.48, rely=0.4, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

logo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("assets/Logo.png"))
logo_label = Label(image=logo_image)
logo_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPJ1F.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set borderwidth=0 and highlightthickness=0 in your Label options. So for your logo_label widget, the modification would look like:

```js
logo_label = Label(image=logo_image, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
```